# The PHP form output from one file to other PHP file's division

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two php pages. In first php page I have two divisions, where in one division I have hyperlinked text which on click showing result in other division of same page, with the help of ajax. The code for same is below:

```
 <body>

  <div id="container">

  <div id="content"> Sidebar <p> &nbsp; </p>
<div class="form">
  <pre>

   <a href=sample_disease_form.php><b>Disease</b></a><p>
   <a href=sample_drug_form.php><b>Drug</b></a><p>

  </pre>


    </form>
</div>
   </div>

   <div id="sidebar"> 

   </div>
   </body>
```

Ajax code for this is:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').each(function(){ 
   $(this).on("click",function(e) {

    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sidebar').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
   });
  });
  </script>
```

Now, I have other PHP file, one which is opening after clicking hyperlink on same page but in other division, contains form. After being clicked submit button of this form I want the result gets displayed in same division but it will come from different PHP file. How can I achieve this?

The second file's code is below:

```
 <pre><h2>  Drug  </h2></pre>
  <pre><p><span class="error"> * required field </span></p></pre>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   <pre> Name: <input type="text" name="drug" value="<?php echo $drug;?>"><span        class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>


  <input type="checkbox" name="drug[]" value="disease">Disease</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="drug[]" value="target">chemical

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></pre>
  </form>
```

Since I am very new to these kinds of programming stuff, expecting help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to submit the page through ajax and load the result in the same div

Comment: How can I do that? Any hint would be of great help.